# How to play recorded video in another Activity by passing in intent in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-videoview

I am recording a video and passing its path into VideoView Activity. But the video can't be opened. Can anyone please help?

RecordActivity - video path function-:

```
 public static String getVideoFilePath() {
    return getAndroidMoviesFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM_dd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + "rangeela.mp4";
  }
```

Its returning ->

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/202209_02-231740rangeela.mp4

        File mediaFile = new File(getVideoFilePath());
        Uri uri= Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,VideoEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("uri",uri.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
```

VideoViewActivity

```
 Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null){
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(bundle.getString("uri"));
        Log.e("video path = ", String.valueOf(uri));
        binding.videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        binding.videoView.start();
    }
```

But I am getting an error

> Can't play this video

How to pass the recorded video in intent and play in another activity?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
String path = getAndroidMoviesFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM_dd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + "rangeela.mp4";

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,VideoEditorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("video",path);
        }
    });
```

**VideoViewActivity**

```
VideoView view = findViewById(R.id.videoview);

  String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("video");
  view.setVideoPath(path);
  view.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but still the same error.